# Binding to code behind from custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView that has several buttons. One of them is defined by the following template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="SubjectItemTemplate">
        <Canvas Width="340" Height="170" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Controls:ThreeImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                              NormalStateImageSource="{Binding NormalImage}"
                                              HoverStateImageSource="{Binding HoverImage}"
                                              PressedStateImageSource="{Binding PressedImage}" Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToUnitsPage}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">


        </Controls:ThreeImageButton>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I have a custom control as you can see, called ThreeImageButton. The button works fine when I use it on its own. But when I have it in the DataTemplate it won't bind properties to the code behind.

Right now, I have

```
x:Name="MyThreeImageButton"
```

in the custom button definition. And I connect to the code-behind like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyThreeImageButton, Path=NormalStateImageSource}"/>
```

(This is just a test to display the text, in the actual code I would assign an image source to another property that is referred to by an  element).

Right now, nothing is displayed in the TextBlock. What is the correct binding syntax I'm supposed to use to reach my properties?

Thanks!

Edit: I am setting the variable in the InitializeComponent function and I am using SetValue on the DependencyProperty.

Edit: Let me add the following information to be more clear

Scenario I: 
In DataTemplate for GridView:

```
<UserControl CustomParameter="Literal Text">
```

In UserControl:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomParameter}">
```

in UserControl .cs: this.DataContext = this
works!

Scenario II:
In DataTemplate for GridView:

```
<UserControl CustomParameter="{Binding ValueFromDataItem">
```

In UserControl:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomParameter}">
```

in UserControl .cs: this.DataContext = this
nope!

Comment: no one has any clue ?

Comment: I assume that you use the `DataTemplate` in a list of some kind. Then the template's `DataContext` is set to the item it represents. Therefore you have to specify the binding source differently. E.g. with static / dynamic resources or relative source.

Comment: did you try set binding from cs file?

Comment: Are your Properties in the UserControl just properties? Or are they DependencyProperties? Also, you're using Mvvm, right? Can you not just bind to the command in the VM? If the VM is in the Item (the data context), then you can access it directly through the Path. It seems this is not the case though. Is the command a property of the Control itself? If that's the case, you can use RelativeSource Self, though this is not the suggested method of doing this.

Comment: I want to display buttons in my gridview. The buttons are represented by particular items (SubjectItem class). In this class I set the sources for the different button images. In the custom button class I can of course just bind directly to the SubjectItem class. But then would remove a lot of flexibility. I want to be able to set the button image sources in the SubjectItemTemplate (above) so that I can either pass the source from the SubjectItem (<ThreeButtonImage NormalStateImageSource={Binding NormalImage}>) or I can manually enter something

Comment: <ThreeButtonImage NormalStateImageSource="some manual reference">. This is needed because I will also have a snapped state template. I don't want to create two different buttons. So basically I have a custom button in a data template. I want to pass parameters to this button either manual or from the item data context. And I want to be able to access this from the cs of the custom button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see,

So setting up a two-way binding to a custom property in a user control can be tricky because a user control cannot bind to a CLR property. Not only that but setting the data context on a user control has an unexpected effect on the binding inside it.

You can solve these problems with a little slight of code. Basically back your CLR properties with dependency properties and set the data context on a child element instead of the root user control.

Take a look at this sample. Let's pretend you have the following MainPage. That MainPage will eventually use our custom user control. So let's set the stage.

**Here's the code-behind:**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new /* your view model */
        {
            Title = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        };
    }
}
```

In the code above I am simulating a complex view model with a simple anonymous class. It would be silly for you to implement your own like this, but at the same time it is silly for me to build a simple sample with the complete scaffolding. I bring this up only so it does not confuse you - as it could look like I am suggesting this approach in prod.

**Here's the XAML:**

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyUserControl Text="{Binding Title}" />
</Grid>
```

In the XAML above, there is absolutely nothing special. I already have reference to the user control in the local namespace and I simply declare it here.

Okay, now that we have a consumer of the control, it's worth pointing out that in testing developers can mistakenly think that their binding is working because they test with literal values. Literal values bind fine. It's binding from the underlying view model that hick-ups.

> Let's say another thing, some developers tend to avoid dependency properties because the require a little more typing. People remember that [kbd]propdp[/kbd] is a handy Visual Studio snippet that stubs out a dependency property for you.

Take a look at this user control. It has two controls, a TextBox and a TextBlock which are there to demonstrate the OneWay and TwoWay functionality of this binding approach. We also implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the user control. For the most part, adding a view model in the case of a user control is overkill because the user control already acts like a view model. It's up to the developer, but it seems dumb to me.

**Here's the code behind:**

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    // text property

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValueDp(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), null);

    // bindable

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        SetValue(property, value);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In the ode above, I have create a "Text" property and backed it with a dependency property. For a matter of reuse I have also implemented SetValueDp() which could be used again and again if I had more than a single property. Even though this demo has but one, I wanted to include this because the repetitive logic should certainly be abstracted out like this.

**Here's the XAML:**

```
<Grid Background="Black" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=userControl}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
            MinHeight="100" Padding="15" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="50" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
            MinHeight="100" Padding="15" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the XAML above, I do nothing special insofar as binding. The syntax simply binds to the Text property using the Mode appropriate to the control. Just like you would do normally. However, what's worth noticing is that the DataContext is NOT set on the user control. Instead, it is set on the Grid. As a point of fact, any control in the tree other than the user control could be used like this. Just don't set the data context of the user control.

**That is it by the way.**

I have tested it to make sure it works. Demonstrating both one and two way binding is pretty handy here. I might even turn this into a blog in case other developers want to find it and don't discover this question. Thanks for your question!

Best of luck!

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Just got back from Build so have been out of pocket. You should delete your comment implying that it does not work, so future developers don't assume it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out today and come back to let you know if it solved my issue!

Comment: It's still not working for me. Mind you that my user control is within a data template that's used in a GridView. I shall create a skeleton project today. I'll post a GIT link at some point here.

Comment: I wrote this for you http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html

Comment: sorry i haven't looked at it yet. this is how things go as a contractor. i had to create a hack solution and abandon c# for a while to continue an iOS 7 update for my clients other app :) thank you though, and when i return to c# land i will give it a go!

Answer (score -1):

As the comments alluded to, your DataTemplate is placing the datacontext of the items to whatever object you are adding to your list.  This is not the same as the surrounding user control's data context.  If you want to reference that datacontext's commands, do the following in the DataTemplate's bindings:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.NormalImage}
```

What this is saying is to go out and find the user control ancestor and use its datacontext and then look for the NormalImage property.  If you run into problems, check your output window for binding errors.  It is very helpful in finding binding problems.

Comment: it can't find "AncestorType". I'm writing a Windows 8 Store app